# Test a custom function in erlang-shell directly

Tags: erlang-shell

I have to test a function in erlang shell. I don't want to write a module and test i.e.  `erl> c(module_name)`.

is there any way to test my sample erlang function directly?
like :

```
    a() -> 1.
```

Throwing error :

```
(my_project@laxmikant)7> a()->1.
* 1: syntax error before: '->'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand, you want to define function directly in shell and play with it. Then wrap functionality you want to test with fun/anonymous function, example:

```
13> ShellFunction = fun(X) -> io:format("Some logic in my function"), 2*2 end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
14> ShellFunction(4).
Some logic in my function4
```

It is only good for small pieces of code you want to test in shell.

Comment: Yeah, I want it for small pieces of code only. Otherwise writing module is good. Thanks I ws looking for the same!